# How to calculate average test score

Tags: java, average

The homework problem is to write a program that adds together all the scores from a class exam and find the average.

I have two questions. To find the average, you have to divide the total score by the number of test takers. I don't know how to record how many test takers there are.

Does the method for getting the average go in the while loop or outside the while loop?

```
import acm.program.*;


public class AvgScore extends ConsoleProgram {
   public void run(){
   println("This program averages the test scores of an exam until the SENTINEL is entered     ."); 


   int total = 0;

   while(true) {
       int score = readInt("enter the test score: ");
       if (score == SENTINEL) break;  
       total += score; 
            }

  println("the average for the class was");

    }

  private static final int SENTINEL = -1; 

  }
```

Comment: Why don't you increment a counter variable by one inside of the while loop?

Comment: you should keep track of number of values (other than SENTINEL) input to your program and once you are out of the loop, should use that count to calculate the average.

Comment: Hint though: when you do the division, cast one of the numbers to double.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way of calculating the average without using count++? I have not seen that yet and I'm wondering if there was another way of doing it with just the information above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a count variable for every read

```
int count=0

while(true) {
  int score = readInt("enter the test score: ");
  if (score == SENTINEL) break;  
  total += score; 
  count++;
}
```

the calculate the average

```
double avg = (double)total/count;
```

Comment: 1) int division. 2) recommending non-standard java variable naming to a newbie.

Comment: You forgot `int count = 0;` before the `while(true)`.

Comment: I didn't even declare the variable its just a piece of code. Here let me change it

Comment: And another downvote for resolving homeworks ... ! Just kidding... but Hovercraft is right, teach them well !